# Using colwise, is.numeric in ddply in R for quantile calculation

Tags: r, plyr, summary, quantile

I am working in R, trying to use the colwise(function, is.numeric) command in ddply and I cannot get it to work for specific quantiles. I would like the 25th quantile, but when you are doing this function over multiple numeric columns, I cannot get it to work.

Here is the example I am working with:

```
d <- data.frame(groups=c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4), rep("C",4)),
        otu1 = runif(12, min=0, max=100),
        otu2 = runif(12, min=0, max=100),
        otu3 = runif(12, min=0, max=100)
        )
```

I can get other summary functions to work:

```
library(plyr)
medians<-ddply(data, c("groups"), colwise(median, is.numeric))
```

However, the quantile function gives me all 5 options, and I cannot figure out how to use colwise with is.numeric when I am defining a specific quantile:

```
highq<-ddply(data, c("groups"), colwise(quantile, is.numeric))  #works but does not give you a specific quantile
highq<-ddply(data, c("groups"), colwise(quantile(is.numeric, probs=0.75), is.numeric))  #does not work
```

I have tried multiple iterations, and have failed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to use `as.numeric`?. Is numeric will just return a TRUE/FALSE value.

Comment: is.numeric works in colwise--this way, it does the function across all numeric columns. In my larger dataset, I usually have other categorical columns (such as the 'group' column) that are skipped by using is.numeric.

Comment: Got it. Didn't understand that `colwise`'s second argument was a logical vector that restricted its effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[,lapply(.SD, quantile, probs=0.75) , groups]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(quantile(., probs=0.75)))
```